# Pop-up in epub file showing content of two or more pages

Tags: javascript, css, epub, epub3

I search in this site with interest the questions that referred to the footnotes of the page . However this was not enough to solve my problem.
I'm making an epub containing :
4 versions of the Bible (CEI 2008, CEI 1974, Interfaith and Nova Vulgate);
Some writings contain references to one or more verses of the Bible.
Well. I wanted to create a pop -up in the presence of these references, to show me the verse in question in the four possible versions.
It being understood that the style of the 4 references can be formatted or surrounded at will via CSS (for example, a different color for each version, maybe surrounded by a 1em border ), I am in trouble, now 15 days to find information both in Italian, but also in English, about how to solve it.
Considering the fact that the epub may also contain any JavaScript code, I wonder if you have any idea about it.
Thank you in advance.
Emanuele Tinari

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. You need to state your problem clearly. What code did you try? What EPUB version and reading applications do you target? (E.g., there are no "popup" in EPUB 2, not all EPUB 3 apps supports popups and/or Javascript)

Comment: Also, are you trying to use the EPUB 3 `epub:type` as in https://gist.github.com/NickBarreto/9811005 ? Or are you using Javascript to make the popup appear?